# How to escape the percent sign in URL in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi, query-string

I have an API with parameters.
In my OpenAPI documentation I used the `allowReserved: true` property to escape special characters, but unfortunately one parameter contains the % sign which is not in the list.

Is there any possibility to escape the % sign?

```yaml
      - name: sig
        in: query
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        allowReserved: true
```

This is from the [Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query):

> Additionally, the `allowReserved` keyword specifies whether the reserved characters `:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=` in parameter values are allowed to be sent as they are, or should be percent-encoded. By default, allowReserved is false, and reserved characters are percent-encoded. For example, `/` is encoded as `%2F` (or `%2f`), so that the parameter value `quotes/h2g2.txt` will be sent as `quotes%2Fh2g2.txt`

Comment: `allowReserved: true` does NOT escape special chars, it sends them as is. The `false` value gets them escaped.

Answer (score 3):

Because the percent character % has a [special meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent_character) in query strings (it's an indicator of percent-encoded octets), clients are supposed to *always encode* % as %25 when this character is used literally in the query string. Servers, in their turn, decode %25 back to % when processing requests.

This is the default behavior and does not require any special attributes in the OpenAPI document.

[image: A screenshot of Swagger Editor that shows a request with a query parameter. The parameter value contains the % character, which is automatically encoded as %25 in the "try it out" request.]

Comment: correct. it is exactly what I want to skip. if I pass aaa%bbb I want as URL encoded aaa%bbb and not aaa%25bbb

Comment: You can't. This is against [RFC 3986 section 2.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.4). No RFC-compliant HTTP client will do that. RFC states that literal % in query strings must always be sent as %25, and servers are supposed to decode %25 back into % when processing the request.